# How to assert an exception is expected

Tags: f#, .net-core, expecto

I'm on a Mac running F# using .NET Core 2.0.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
let rec evaluate(x: string) =
  match x with
  // ... cases
  | _ -> failwith "illogical"
```

I'd like to write an Expecto test that validates that the exception is thrown as expected, something along the lines of:

```
// doesn't compile
testCase "non-logic" <| fun _ ->
  Expect.throws (evaluate "Kirkspeak") "illogical"
```

The error is

> This expression was expected to have type
>       'unit -> unit' but here has type 'char'

`unit -> unit` makes me this is analogous to `Assert.Fail`, which is not what I want.

Being somewhat new to F# and Expecto, I'm having trouble locating a working example of asserting that an exception is thrown as expected. Does anyone have one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Expect.throws` has the signature `(unit -> unit) -> string -> unit` so the function you want to test must be (unit -> unit) or be wrapped inside a function that is (unit -> unit).

```
let rec evaluate (x: string) : char =
  match x with
  // ... cases
  | _ -> failwith "illogical"
```

The compiler error is telling you that the function you passed to Expect.throws does not have the right signature yet.

```
[<Tests>]
let tests = testList "samples" [
    test "non-logic" {
      // (evaluate "Kirkspeak") is (string -> char)
      // but expecto wants (unit -> unit)
      Expect.throws (evaluate "Kirkspeak") "illogical"
    }
]

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Tests.runTestsInAssembly defaultConfig argv
```

One way to make it work is to change

```
Expect.throws (evaluate "Kirkspeak") "illogical"
```

to

```
// you could instead do (fun () -> ...)
// but one use of _ as a parameter is for when you don't care about the argument
// the compiler will infer _ to be unit
Expect.throws (fun _ -> evaluate "Kirkspeak" |> ignore) "illogical"
```

Now expecto is happy!

[image: expecto says the test asserting an exception throws passes]

This answer was the way I thought through it. It is usually helpful to follow the type signatures.

EDIT: I saw your error message saying `This expression was expected to have type 'unit -> unit' but here has type 'char'` so I updated my answer to match it.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is headed in the right direction! However, when I run this code, the exception isn't caught. Are you running this against .NET  Framework or .NET Core? (I'm on a Mac.)

Comment: That's strange. I pulled all the code I put in the answer from a netcoreapp2.0 console project. Are you getting some kind of further message?

Comment: Yes, Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Exception
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in tests.dll but was not handled in user code: 'illogical'
   at Tests.testingExceptions@121-1.Invoke(Unit _arg1) in /Users/.../tests/Tests.fs:line 121
   at Expecto.Expect.throws(FSharpFunc`2 f, String message)

Comment: Is it possible to share the test code project in a github gist or something? I think this sounds like some syntax issue now. Otherwise I am not sure how I can help further.

Comment: If it helps, here is my source https://github.com/gfritz/fsharp-stack. `dotnet run` should result in my screenshot.

Comment: I had a moment to download it, and it's having trouble finding FSharp.Core 4.5. I don't have time to troubleshoot today, but let's assume it's a local setup issue for the moment.